# Scene kit shape distorted

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

We built an iOS app to render 3D objects using Scene kit.
We are plotting based upon coordinates(Vertices) received and populating our scene view inside Table cell. This code is working fine when we are testing on our system With Xcode  [When testing from Xcode on our local system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th81q.png)

But when we are publishing our app through Azure CI/CD pipeline to App centre that application is rendering shapes incorrectly.[When testing from App centre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqqWm.png)

How to resolve this issue or find out reason behind this behaviour ?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? this is the same challenge I'm facing

Answer (score 0):

It was due to calculations I was doing for vertex values.
For values received, some calculations I was required to perform before rendering shapes.So, when doing in xCode that was properly rendered but when releasing it classes and functions are shortened for better compression.

For class where calculations was happening that you can check by adding logs.